# boostrap modal change location onClick not to dismiss

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this bootstrap modal containing a button with a close class that dismisses the modal, I intend to use the button to change the window.location not just dismiss the modal, kindly help:

```
<div class='modal fade' id='alert' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
  <div class='modal-dialog'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
      <div class='modal-header bg-primary'>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class='modal-title'>&nbsp;Hello world/h4>
      </div>
      <div class='modal-body'>

<p>Hello world </p>

</div>
      <div class='modal-footer'>
        <button class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal' >Close</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->   


//jquery to change location doesn't work?
<script>
$('.close').click(function()
{
    if($('.close').click())
    {
        window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/product.asp?IDnum=1';
    }
});
```

Comment: The line `if($('.close').click()) {` is unnecessary and actually triggers a `click` event on ALL elements with the `close` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `data-dismiss` attribute from `close` button. And you need to place the place script inside `document.ready` function.

Note that the close button should have the id `close`

```
$(function() {
      $('#close').click(function() {
        window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/product.asp?IDnum=1';
      });
});
```

Here is the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/nUO6frEyTzqlctcpMNmq?p=preview).

Comment: you rock, thanks a million and I'm happy to be a stack(er)